# Equating large lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Lets say I have a list of undefined variables `{a1,a2,a3,a4}`. I could type out each element by hand, but if I wanted to eventually extend the list, it would be easier generate the list by `Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 4}]`.

Now, lets say I want to assign values to each element. In the first method when I type it out by hand, I simply put `{a1,a2,a3,a4} = {1,2,3,4}`, then I get the result that I wanted: a1=1, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4.

Now, if I try to assign to each element a value using the second method, I would think it would make sense to put `Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 4}] = {1,2,3,4}`. However, it gives me an error.

How can I equate a variable list generated by the table function to another list? I have tried about 5 different methods, and the only thing that seems to work is to copy and paste the output from the table function into a new kernel, but this is not an elegant solution at all.

Comment: Are you sure `Indexed` cannot meet your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Evaluate[Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 4}]] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

You need to ensure that the first argument of `Set` (`=`) is actually evaluated, because `Table` is protected, but it will handle `List` as expected once `Table` is evaluated.

Comment: thank you so much!